# Need help to print last symbol of string

Tags: java, arrays, string

//For each string of array args print the string, its length, its first symbol, and its last symbol.

```
public class A8b {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]); //print the string
            System.out.println(args[i].length()); //length of string
            System.out.println(args[i].substring(0,1)); //its first symbol
            System.out.println(args[i].length()-1); //its last symbol  <<----------
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is how to print the last symbol of string? I'm trying to do it this way

```
System.out.println(args[i].length()-1);//its last symbol
```

but it gives me a wrong answer. Does anybody can help me?

Comment: Use `substring` like you did for first symbol.

Comment: you are almost there, just combine substring() and length() appropriately.

Comment: `args[i].substring(args[i].length-1)` ?

Comment: @alfasin you are not helping OP learn.

Comment: You can use :  args[i].substring(args[i].length()-1) or args[i].charAt(args[i].length()-1)

Answer (score 0):

From a basic string `str`, to get the last char you can to `substring at the index`length-1 **:** `str.substring(str.length()-1)`

*So here* : `args[i].substring(args[i].length-1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to get the first character, you can do the same with substring to get the last, but just point it to the last character:

```
int lastIdx = args[i].length()-1;
System.out.println(args[i].substring(lastIdx)); //its last symbol
```

Alternatively, you can use `charAt(index_of_last_char)`:

```
System.out.println(args[i].charAt(lastIdx)); //its last symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

From javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-

> ```
> public String substring​(int beginIndex,
>                         int endIndex)
> ```
>
> Returns a string that is a substring of this string.
>    The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.
>
> ```
> Examples:
>
>      "hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"
>      "smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"
>
>
> Parameters:
>     beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
>     endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.
> ```

So in your case code for extract last symbol from string will be like that:

```
String abc = "abc";
String c = abc.substring(abc.length() - 1, abc.length());
System.out.println(c); // c
```